# How to test i18n in next.js 13 by listening url changes or useRouter methods calls

Tags: typescript, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library, next.js13

I am trying to test the language change, I have tried to test clicking on the language button to check that the url changes, but I cannot get it to make the call.

**Component:**

*LangButtons.tsx*

```js
import useTranslations from '@/hooks/useTranslations'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const LangButtons = () => {
   const { asPath } = useRouter()
   const { currentLang, langs } = useTranslations()

   return(
     <nav>
       {langs!.map(
         (lang) =>
           currentLang !== lang && (
             <Link key={lang} locale={lang} href={asPath}>
               <div role="button">{lang.split('-')[0]}</div>
             </Link>
           ),
       )}
     </nav>
   )
}

export default LangButtons
```

**Test:**

*LangButtons.test.tsx*

```js
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import LangButtons from '.'

const mockRouter = jest.fn()

jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
   ...jest.requireActual('next/router'),
   useRouter: () => mockRouter(),
}))

jest.mock('@/hooks/useTranslations', () => () => ({
   currentLang: 'en-AR',
   langs: ['en-US', 'es-AR', 'pt-BR'],
}))

describe('LangButtons', () => {
   it('should change path on button click', () => {
     const onMock = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true))
     const emitMock = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true))
     const pushMock = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true))

     mockRouter.mockImplementation(() => ({
       push: pushMock,
       prefetch: () => Promise.resolve(true),
       asPath: 'pt-BR',
       events: {
         off: jest.fn(),
         emit: emitMock,
         on: onMock,
       },
     }))

     render(<LangButtons />)

     const portugueseButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /pt/i })
     fireEvent.click(portugueseButton)

     expect(pushMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
     expect(emitMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
     expect(onMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
   })
})
```

**Hook that I use in the LangButtons.tsx component**

*useTranslations.ts*

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import languages, { TranslationFile } from '@/locales/resources'

const useTranslations = () => {
   const { locale, locales } = useRouter()
   const translations = languages[locale!] as TranslationFile

   return { translations, currentLang: locale, langs: locales }
}

export default use Translations
```

**resources.ts**

```js
import EN from './translation-en.json'
import ES from './translation-es.json'
import PT from './translation-pt.json'

export type TranslationFile = typeof import('./translation-en.json')

interface Languages {
   [keyof:string]:TranslationFile
}

const languages: Languages = {
   'en-US': EN,
   'es-AR': IS,
   'pt-BR': PT,
}

export default languages
```

I have made several attempts, such as trying to get the modified path through the window.location object, testing properties such as `href`, `pathname`, among others. As shown in the current code. I've also tried listening for method calls inside the `useRouter` object without success, and out of the different ways to mock `useRouter`, the one used in the snippet I passed was the only one that really did the trick. I based myself on this article, I recommend it.
[Jest Mock](https://www.bam.tech/en/article/fix-jest-mock-cannot-access-before-initialization-error)